# How to load external html into html inside Django template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to incorporate a django application into a web site where static html accounts for the majority.
The directory structure is as follows.

```
root/
　├ var/
　│　 └ www/
　│　　　├ html/
　│　　　    ├ static
　│　　　    │  ├style.css
　│　　　    │  ├base.js
　│　　　    │ 
　│　　　    ├ web/
　│　　　　　     ├head.html
　│　　　　　     ├footer.html
　│　　　　　     ├base.html
　│
　└ opt/
　　　└ django/
　　　　　├ project/
　　　　　│
　　　　　├ apps/
　　　　　├　├ views.py
　　　　　 　├ template/
　　　　　 　     ├ index.html
```

I want to make `/opt/django/template/index.html` read html in `/var/www/html/web/`.
I do not know how to include.

`{% include "/var/www/html/web/head.html" %}`was useless.
I do not want to change the directory structure.

Comment: How about creating a symlink from your templates folder to the original?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering this as your directory structure:

```
root/
　├ var/
　│　 └ www/
　│　　　├ html/
　│　　　    ├ static
　│　　　    │  ├style.css
　│　　　    │  ├base.js
　│　　　    │ 
　│　　　    ├ web/
　│　　　　　     ├head.html
　│　　　　　     ├footer.html
　│　　　　　     ├base.html
　│
　└ opt/
　　　└ django/
　　　　　├ project/
　　　　　│
　　　　　├ apps/
　　　　　├　├ views.py
　　　　　 　├ template/
　　　　　 　     ├ index.html
```

To use */var/www/html/web/head.html* in your index.html.
Go to your settings.py and add this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps/template'),'/var/www/html/web/']
        ,
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Now go to your index.html.

```
{% include "head.html" %}
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `/var/www/html/web/` to the `DIRS` option in the template configuration dictionary in your project settings.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-DIRS

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['/var/www/html/web/'], # won't work on Windows
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ... some options here ...
        },
    },
]
```

Then:

```
{% include "head.html" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your templates can go anywhere you want. Your template directories are by using the DIRS option in the TEMPLATES setting in your settings file.
For each app in INSTALLED_APPS, the loader looks for a templates subdirectory. If the directory exists, Django looks for templates in there.

#### note

Paths should use Unix-style forward slashes, even on Windows.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            '/var/www/html/web/',
        ],
    },
]
```